# Processing text files and hyphenating strings line by line in Java

Tags: java, stringbuilder, textinput

I have a .txt file with 8,000 rows in a single column. Each line contains either an alphanumeric or a number like this:

> 0219381A
>
> 10101298
>
> 32192017
>
> 1720291C
>
> 04041009

I'd like to read this file, insert a 0 (zero) before each beginning digit, a hyphen in between digits 3 and 4, and then remove the remaining digits to an output file like this:

> 002-19
>
> 010-10
>
> 032-19
>
> 017-20
>
> 004-04

I'm able to read from and write to a file or insert a hyphen when done separately but can't get the pieces working together:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("file1.txt");

          while(in.hasNextLine())
          {

                 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(in.nextLine());
                 builder.insert(0, "0");
                 builder.insert(3, "-");
                 String hyph = builder.toString();
                 out.printf(hyph);
          }
          in.close();
          out.close();
```

How can I get these pieces working together/is there another approach?

Comment: Please post your code directly, not external links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        if (!line.isEmpty()) {
            line = "0" + line.substring(0, 2) + "-" + line.substring(2, 4);
        }
        out.println(line);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, Evgeniy. unfortunately didn't work. error thrown is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
       at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
       at writer.splitWords.main(splitWords.java:16)

Comment: try String line = in.nextLine().trim()

Answer (score 0):

You code looks fine. If you make this changes, you should be good i feel :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(in.nextLine().substring(0,4));
```